# Routing Table issue in routing multiple url with same schema

Tags: c#, routes

the code :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Partners Details", "Partner/{PartnerName}", "~/Partners/PartnerDetails.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary());
    routes.MapPageRoute("Partners Offers", "Partner/{PartnerID}", "~/Partners/Partners.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary());
}
```

those routes Url can be called from different link tag in default.aspx page but the problem is when i try to access partners.aspx it would redirect me to PartnerDetails.aspx i am confused why is that weird behavior ? and what is solution for it ?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that the routes are identical **except for** the data types. However, you haven't specified the `constraints` for those routes. So let's do that:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Partners Details",
    "Partner/{PartnerName}",
    "~/Partners/PartnerDetails.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary(),
    new RouteValueDictionary() {
        "PartnerName", "[a-zA-Z\s]"
    });

routes.MapPageRoute("Partners Offers",
    "Partner/{PartnerID}",
    "~/Partners/Partners.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary(),
    new RouteValueDictionary() {
        "PartnerID", @"\d"
    });
```

but let's break this down. The `constraints` use Regex to determine if the string value in the location of the key (e.g. PartnerID) matches. If it doesn't, the route is skipped, and it moves on to the next one. But I want you to think about why it wasn't working also. Let's say you had to write the code to interpret the routes and you got a link like this:

```
http://.../Partner/123
```

doesn't that match `"Partner/{PartnerName}"`? I mean `{PartnerName}` isn't typed by any means, it's just a placeholder right?

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: but i still have one question if let's say i have another route like : routes.MapPageRoute("Partners Offers",
    "Store/{StoreID}",
    "~/Stores/Store.aspx",
    false,
    new RouteValueDictionary(),
    new RouteValueDictionary() {
        "StoreID", @"\d"
    }); i think the problem may still here right ?

Comment: @Sora, I'm not sure I follow. That's a completely different route than the ones above. Based on the way you have it defined it should work just fine.

Comment: i wanted to show an idea but i guess i give the wrong example um let's say it's the same route but instead of PartnerId i send let's say StoreID we can see that PartnerId and storeId are both Id's so the regex is valid for the two integer provided how the route Table could guess that this is partnerId not storeId ?

Comment: @Sora, that is a bit more complex of an issue. It's going to pick the first one that matches. I would say you're going to need to either preface the id with something, like `p123` vs. `s123` and the pull that integer off in the controller -or you're going to need to change the route to be something like `Partner/Store/{StoreID}`.